# Chinese characters encoding issue golang

Tags: csv, go, encoding, character

I am trying to write to a file a string that contains chinese characters but I have an encoding issue (getting something like that 10 Âπ¥‰ª•‰∏äÁªèÈ™å)

Here is what I have.

```
csvContent, err := gocsv.MarshalString(&csvTranslation) // Get all clients as CSV string
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    d1 := []byte(string(csvContent))
    ioutil.WriteFile("result.csv", d1, 0644)
```

Could you point me to what I am missing

Answer (score 1):

You have a Go UTF-8 encoded `string` and you are incorrectly interpreting it as extended ASCII bytes.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    utf8 := "汉字 漢字"
    fmt.Println(utf8)
    var ascii string
    for i := 0; i < len(utf8); i++ {
        ascii += string(utf8[i])
    }
    fmt.Println(ascii)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/HTPWhPO7OVS

Output:

```
汉字 漢字
æ±å­ æ¼¢å­
```